# How to cancel Pan Guesture Events while reordering cells in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer, uiresponder

I have an Audio Player View Controller that has a pan gesture recognizer added to its view. On detecting a pan I animate a UIView containing a child vc in it(that is for the queued tracks). This child vc has a table view in editing mode to allow reordering of music tracks.
Now the issue is when I try to reorder tableview rows the pan guesture handler in parent view controller's view gets called and hence reorder does not work.
What I want is to cancel any pan events generated in the child vc and let the tableview handle it's default implementation of reordering the cells.

Here's my code:
1. In AudioPlayerViewController initializing the view :

```
 lazy var playerQueueContainer:UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        let queueVC = AudioPlayerQueueViewController()
        queueVC.delegate = self
        queueVC.queuedItems = playerItems
        queueVC.currentPlayerItem = startPlayerItem

        queueVC.willMove(toParent: self)
        view.addSubview(queueVC.view)
        self.addChild(queueVC)
        queueVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        queueVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        queueVC.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        queueVC.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        queueVC.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        queueVC.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        return view
    }()
```

2. Implementation of pan guesture handler

```
   @objc func handlePanGesture(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        switch sender.state {
        case .began:
            startInteractiveTransition(state:nextState,duration: 1)
        case .changed:
            let yTranslation = sender.translation(in: self.playerQueueContainer).y
            var fractionComplete = yTranslation/self.queueVCHeight
            fractionComplete = currentQueueState == .collapsed ? -fractionComplete : fractionComplete
            updateInteractiveTransition(fractionCompleted:fractionComplete)
        case .ended:
            continueInteractiveTransition()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

3. Table View Methods in AudioPlayerQueueViewController:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let item = queuedItems?[sourceIndexPath.row]{
            queuedItems?.insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
            delegate?.didMoveItem(from: sourceIndexPath, to: destinationIndexPath)
        }
    }
```

Toggling the cancelsTouchesInView property doesn't work.

I'm sharing a screen recording in the following link for better understanding of the flow:
[screen rec](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1huVvKjDLbZbYtFfzbKo_gsjlEJjluDnu/view?usp=sharing)